# NoResultException not being caught

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Inside my Doctrine Repository I use

```
return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

`getSingleScalarResult` is defined as follows:

```
/**
 * Gets the single scalar result of the query.
 *
 * Alias for getSingleResult(HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR).
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws NonUniqueResultException If the query result is not unique.
 * @throws NoResultException        If the query returned no result.
 */
public function getSingleScalarResult()
{
    return $this->getSingleResult(self::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
}
```

So in my service, I catch these exceptions and try to handle them appropriately:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;
use Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException;

public function getCustomerSpecificPrice(User $user, Product $product)
{
    $initialContract = $this->em->getRepository(Contract::class)
        ->getInitialContract($user);

    try {
        $condition = $this->em->getRepository(ContractCondition::class)
            ->getValidForProduct($initialContract, $product);

        return $condition->getPrice();
    } catch (NoResultException $e) {
        return $product->getPrice();
    } catch (NonUniqueResultException $e) {
        return $product->getPrice();
    }
}
```

Basically, I try to find a valid ContractCondition and if there is none (or too many), I'll just use the standard product price.

The Exceptions are not caught. Why? The docs say on a [side note](http://php.net/manual/de/language.errors.php7.php):

> As with normal exceptions, these Error exceptions will bubble up until
>   they reach the first matching catch block. If there are no matching
>   blocks, then any default exception handler installed with
>   set_exception_handler() will be called, and if there is no default
>   exception handler, then the exception will be converted to a fatal
>   error and will be handled like a traditional error.

I run into the Exception when I load some fixtures in the project:

```
$ bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test -n -v
  > purging database
  > loading [1] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadPageData
  > loading [2] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadAdminData
  > loading [3] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadCompanyData
  > loading [4] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadSchoolData
  > loading [5] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadProductData
  > loading [6] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadBundleData
  > loading [7] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadAvailableExamLanguagesData
  > loading [8] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadInstructorData
  > loading [9] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadStudentData
  > loading [10] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadTimetableData
  > loading [11] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadInstructorScheduleData
  > loading [12] AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadContractData


  [Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException]
  No result was found for query although at least one row was expected.


Exception trace:
 () at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:807
 Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->getSingleResult() at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Repository/ContractRepository.php:475
 AppBundle\Repository\ContractRepository->getInitialContract() at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Service/PricingService.php:25
 AppBundle\Service\PricingService->getCustomerSpecificPrice() at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/Service/ContractService.php:231
 AppBundle\Service\ContractService->createContract() at /var/www/project/src/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadContractData.php:79
 AppBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\LoadContractData->load() at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Executor/AbstractExecutor.php:121
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\AbstractExecutor->load() at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Executor/ORMExecutor.php:83
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\{closure}() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func() at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:233
 Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->transactional() at /var/www/project/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:10714
 DoctrineORMEntityManager_0000000025b0f31f000000000a6fef789ffd066567cf09dff04afe3a5f2f5e93->transactional() at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/data-fixtures/lib/Doctrine/Common/DataFixtures/Executor/ORMExecutor.php:85
 Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Executor\ORMExecutor->execute() at /var/www/project/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Command/LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php:118
 Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand->execute() at /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:854
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:201
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:81
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/project/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:125
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/project/bin/console:29
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the full exception message and stack trace that you get now?

Comment: OK, could you please paste the exception you are receiving?

Comment: Sure, just added the Exception w/ stack trace. Thanks

Comment: The exception is already thrown when you call `getInitialContract()` which is outside the `catch` block.

Comment: Duh, you are right :facepalm: Wasted my whole day with this. Thanks @xabbuh